# bag of words with binary features

Tags: visual-c++

everyone,
I now want to test the binary features (ORB,BRIEF) with the model of bag-of-words. As the model in the Opencv seems did not provided BOW with binary feature. How should I do with it? Thanks

Answer (score -3):

This guy [here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/08/25/a-simple-object-classifier-with-bag-of-words-using-opencv-2-3-w-code/) uses SURF detector & descriptor. You can replace SURF with ORB.

Google "BOW opencv".

Comment: ORB is a type of binary feature. how to extend to the BOW of OpenCV

Comment: SURF uses float descriptors and ORB uses binary decriptors. It can't be used in the same way.